# Limit cpu limit of process in a loop

Tags: bash, loops, ubuntu, ffmpeg, cpu-usage

I am trying to execute `ffmpeg` in a loop over multiple files. I only want one instance to run at a time, and to only use 50% of the cpu. I've been trying `cpulimit` but it isn't playing nice with the loop.

```
for i in {1..9}; do cpulimit -l 50 -- ffmpeg <all the options>; done
```

This spawns all nine jobs at once, and they are all owned by `init` so I have to open `htop` to kill them.

```
for i in {1..9}; do ffmpeg <all the options> & cpulimit -p $! -l 50; done
```

This hangs, `ctrl+c` continues to the next loop iteration. These instances can only be killed by `SIGKILL`.

Comment: I had the same issue, I fixed it using following approach, Just write ffmpeg command to a `txt` file, and everytime I read and execute command if CPU not busy, also remove executed command from `txt` file, If CPU is busy in other process then skip execution of commands, and again read `txt` file after some time,

Comment: have you tried a nice/renice approach?

Comment: @Allan No, my problem is heat build up, not resource contention.

Comment: @harishsharma Sounds like you've implemented a task scheduler UltrasoundJelly suggested.

Comment: Yes, but I created scheduler from basic approach, didn't use any library/repository,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a queue is the way to go.  A simple solution that I use is [Task Spooler](http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/%7Eviric/soft/ts/).  You can limit the number of cores ffmpeg uses with `-threads` also.  Here's some code for you:

```
ts sh -c "ffmpeg -threads 4 -i INPUT.mp4 -threads 4 OUTPUT.mp4"
```

- You can set the max number of simultaneous tasks to 1 with: `ts -S 1`
- To see the current queue just run `ts`
- EDIT: added `-threads 4` before `-i` to limit decoding and encoding CPU usage

Comment: A queue, brilliant! it also happens to help with some other things in general. For (mostly my own) future reference, some of the more advanced schedulers (ie Slurm) allow the fine grained allocation of resources.

Comment: Seems that my ffmpeg could care less about `-threads`. `cpulimit` is not playing nice with `ts` either.

Comment: Interesting.  What architecture and codec are you using?

Comment: It's and AMD Bulldozer (x64) and h264 -> mjpeg

Comment: I was able to achieve something similar with `taskset -c 0,2,4 ffmpeg ...`. Oddly `ffmpeg` is still spawning 10 threads with 4 active running an average of 70% each.

Answer (score 2):

You should run it in foreground. In this way the loop will work as expected.

```
$ cpulimit --help
...
-f  --foreground   launch target process in foreground and wait for it to exit
```

This works for me.

```
for file in *.mp4; do
    cpulimit -f -l 100 -- ffmpeg -i "$file" <your options>
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the -threads option to have an effect on the encoder, you should put it after the -i argument, before the output filename - your current option only tells the decoding part to use a single thread. So to keep it all using a single thread, you want -threads 1 both before and after the -i option. so you can do it like:

```html
ffmpeg -threads 1 -i INPUT.mp4 -threads 1 OUTPUT.mp4
```